# TypeScript interfaces's have an error

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
class Animal {
    name: string;
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    breed: string;
}

// Error: indexing with a 'string' will sometimes get you a Dog!
interface NotOkay {
    [x: number]: Animal;
    [x: string]: Dog;
}
```

Why the interface "NotOkay" has an error. 
but I try to change the interface like below:

```
interface NotOkay {
        [x: string]: Animal;
        [x: number]: Dog;
    }
```

The Error disappear.

Comment: code from:https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript (and therefore TypeScript), property keys are coerced into `string`s.  So if you access a property with a `number` key, you're actually accessing a property with a `string` key:

```
var obj = {3: 'a', four: 'b'};
console.log(obj['3']); // a
console.log(obj[3]); // a
console.log(obj[3] === obj['3']); // true
```

But there are some `string` keys which are not also `number` keys:

```
console.log(obj['four']); // b
```

The TypeScript compiler therefore enforces that the returned value for accessing `number` keys is a special case of the return value for accessing `string` keys.  For example, the following is okay:

```
interface Okay {
  [x: string]: Animal;
  [x: number]: Dog;
}
```

Every time you access an `Okay` with a `number` key, you are actually also accessing it with a `string` key.  And since every `number` key property is a `Dog`, and every `string` key property is an `Animal`, this is saying: every time you get a `Dog` you are actually also getting an `Animal`.  This is verifiably true to the compiler; it knows that `Dog` is a subclass of `Animal` and that every `Dog` is an `Animal`. So TypeScript is happy with `Okay`.

But the following is not okay:

```
interface NotOkay {
  [x: number]: Animal;
  [x: string]: Dog;
}
```

Every time you access a `NotOkay` with a `number` key, you are actually also accessing it with a `string` key.  And since every `number` key property is an `Animal`, and every `string` key property is a `Dog`, this is saying: every time you get an `Animal` you are actually also getting a `Dog`.  This is *not* verifiably true to the compiler; not every `Animal` is necessarily a `Dog`, so TypeScript is *unhappy* with `NotOkay` and complains.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you misinterpreting index signatures? What exactly do you hope to achieve?

```
interface Okay {
    name: string
    size: number
    [propName: string]: any
}
```

This means that `Okay` can have any number of properties, including a Dog and an Animal:

```
// o needs name and size and can have anything else optionally
let o:Okay = {name:'billy', size:2, dog:new Dog(), animal:new Animal()}
```